# c# Intersect a List<Tuple> with List of entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, tuples

I have to find the coincidences in two lists, one of a specific entity and the other is a tuple

The entity is very simple, like this:

```
public class SUBJECT
{
    int id;
    int group;
}
```

The coincidences must be with both properties of the SUBJECT entity, and the two values of the tuple, a list of the SUBJECT.group is required, I wrote this code, but i am guessing there is a better way of doing this.

```
List<SUBJECT> subjects;
List<Tuple<int, int>> groups;
List<int> intersected = new List<int>();
foreach (Tuple<int, int> g in groups)
{
    List<int> found = subjects
                    .Where(x => x.id == item.Item1 && x.group == item.Item2)
                    .Select(x => x.group).ToList();
    if (found != null && found.Any())
        intersected.AddRange(found);
}
return intersected;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would convert subjects into `Tuples`, then use `Intersect`:

```
var intersected = subjects
                  .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.id, x.group))
                  .Intersect(groups)
                  .Select(x => x.group)
                  .ToList();
```

This will work because `Tuples` are compared based on the property values.

Comment: hey, but I want to intersect by the two values (id and group)